# Django regex on template?

Tags: python, django

I need to make menu active based when user visits a page ! And it should also work on sub pages, how to allow everything after a particular word ?

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}

<li class="menu-item {% if url_name in 'settings, settings-password' %}active{% endif %}">
      <a href="{% url 'settings' %}" class="nk-menu-link">
           <span class="menu-text">Settings</span>
       </a>
</li>
{% endwith %}
```

In the above, am adding these `settings, settings-password`, how to allow everything after settings to make the menu active?

I have other pages who has many sub pages, so its not fare to add everything under if In loop, so if i can allow everything after a word,

for ex:

How to make menu active which contains "settings" in their view name?

Comment: Have you tried to write your own custom filter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just check whether 'settings' is the url_name.by doing this...

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}

<li class="menu-item {% if 'settings' in url_name %}active{% endif %}">
      <a href="{% url 'settings' %}" class="nk-menu-link">
           <span class="menu-text">Settings</span>
       </a>
</li>
{% endwith %}
```

if url_name is 'settings or settings_passwords or settings****' then it will always return True and False if not.